# How are these two different?

Tags: python

```
def reverseList(self, head):
    
    prev, curr = None, head
    while curr:
        curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, curr.next
    return prev
```

I don't get the difference between this one above and

```
def reverseList(self, head):
    
    prev, curr = None, head
    while curr:
        curr.next = prev
        prev = curr
        curr = curr.next
    return prev
```

Why do they have different results?
I thought the way of first one and second ones' declaration are same.

Answer (score 1):

In the first function, `curr` is assigned the **old** value of `curr.next`, while in the second function, `curr` is assigned the **new** value of `curr.next`(aka `prev`).

Answer (score 1):

In the first code, when the `curr = curr.next` is executed, `curr.next` was whatever value it was before the "multi-assign" statement.

In the second code, when `curr = curr.next` is executed, `curr.next` has the value that `prev` had, by virtue of the `curr = prev` statement executed earlier.

---

If you want to run the 3-line code with a "multi-assign" statement, you should use:

```py
curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, prev
```

---

This can be easily shown with a helper `ListNode` class (I use `next_` because `next` is a reserved word in Python):

```py
class ListNode:   
    def __init__(self, name=None, next_=None):
        self.name = name
        self.next_ = next_
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'ListNode[{self.name}->{self.next_}]'

    
prev, curr = ListNode('P'), ListNode('C')
print(prev, prev.next_, curr, curr.next_)
curr.next_ = prev
prev = curr
curr = curr.next_
print(prev, prev.next_, curr, curr.next_)
# ListNode[P->None] None ListNode[C->None] None
# ListNode[C->ListNode[P->None]] ListNode[P->None] ListNode[P->None] None


prev, curr = ListNode('P'), ListNode('C')
print(prev, prev.next_, curr, curr.next_)
curr.next_, prev, curr = prev, curr, prev
print(prev, prev.next_, curr, curr.next_)
# ListNode[P->None] None ListNode[C->None] None
# ListNode[C->ListNode[P->None]] ListNode[P->None] ListNode[P->None] None
```

Comment: It seems right. I don't check the result for ```curr.next, prev, curr = prev, curr, prev```, but the idea is right. so I upvote.

Comment: It's a confused to do it in "multi-assign"  way. I have already given up.

Comment: You can use `.next` as an attribute, alright.

Comment: You surely can. I just did not like using it.

Answer (score 0):

They switch value in first approach but in second it assigns variables to each other.

Comment: fist approach :-)

Comment: First, switch the value at the same time; Second, execute step one by one; which means ```curr.next``` in step 3 will be ```prev``` in step 1 ,while ```curr.next ``` is still ```curr.next``` in first

Answer (score 0):

Its because in the first line of code, all the assigning is executed at once using the original values

In the second case, when you assign curr.next to curr, curr.next is already equal to prev as assigned before. So curr gets the value of prev in the end unlike the first approach, where all of them get the original values

Answer (score 0):

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None

head = X(1)
head.next = X(2)
head.next.next = X(3)
head.next.next.next = X(4)
head.next.next.next.next = X(5)

prev, curr = None, head

while curr:
    tmp = curr.next #Here...
    curr.next = prev
    prev = curr
    curr = tmp #and here.
    
while prev:
    print(prev.value)
    prev = prev.next
```

For the second example (i.e without variable exchanging), you need a temporary variable to store the value of `curr.next`.